# ESXi SSH session exit kills running job - nohup same result

Tags: ssh, process, nohup, esxi

I have a script on ESXi that I need to be able to ssh into, execute the script, disown the process and exit ssh session, while keeping the process running?  I have tried executing it the following ways:

nohup /etc/run_command

nohup /etc/run_comand &

I have also run across trying this example: ([Website - Sudoall.com](http://sudoall.com/how-to-quit-esxi-ssh-and-leave-background-tasks-running/))

exec </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

but I must not be using it right, because I get the same results.

Is there a way to disown the process, exit the ssh session without killing the running process on ESXi?

---- Update ----

After a lot of google research, I stumbled across this [Website](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/).  ESXi does not have screen, tmux, or disown.  An nohup was not working...I gave setsid a shot, and it worked.

setsid /etc/run_command &

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of google research, I stumbled across this [Website](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/). ESXi does not have screen, tmux, or disown. An nohup was not working...I gave setsid a shot, and it worked.

setsid /etc/run_command &